# In MVC, how do I handle optional rendering of content in a view based on complex logic?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to achieve some authorization checks in my view which are of more complex logic than simply checking for the current role. Basically I want to output certain parts only to the users who are authorized for it. Basically I want to do this in my view:

```
<p>Everyone can read this</p>
@if(ComplexAuthorizationLogic())
{
    <p>Only authorized can read this</p>
}
```

The only option I can think of is to add properties to my model but I have to do this in so many places so lots of code duplication which doesn't feel right.

First of all, am I even thinking about this problem in the right way or should I handle it completely different? If not, what would you recommend?

Comment: Put ComplexAuthorizationLogic() in a static class, possibly in the root namespace (so that you aren't required to add the namespace your web.config or add a using statement to the view).

Comment: you can do the calculation in contoller and send it in view bag and use it in the view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I accomplish this:

Create a helper/utility class, similar to the one below.

```
namespace Your.Root.Namespace
{
    public partial class SecurityProvider
    {
        public static bool HasAnyRole(params string[] roles)
        {
            bool hasAnyRole = false;
            if (IsUserAuthenticated())
            {
                var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
                var services = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMembershipService>();

                hasAnyRole = services.UserHasAnyRole(user.Identity.Name, roles);
            }

            return hasAnyRole;
        }

        public static bool IsUserAuthenticated()
        {
            bool isAuthenticated = false;
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
            if (user != null && user.Identity != null)
            {
                isAuthenticated = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            }

            return isAuthenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the relevant method in your view.

```
@if(SecurityProvider.HasAnyRole("Admin"))
{
    <div>
        This is classified content! You must be an Admin to see this!
    </div>
}
```

You can find the entire class in a [sample project I made](https://github.com/tiesont/cookie-mvc/blob/master/CookieMVC/CookieMVC.Web/Security/SecurityProvider.cs).

Comment: Thanks! Works nicely!